# What is the correct way? CSS Link Pseudo-Class

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I just found this:

> **Note**: a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS
>   definition in order to be effective!!
>
> **Note**: a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order
>   to be effective!!
>
> **Note**: Pseudo-class names are not case-sensitive.

Does this mean that this is **INCORRECT**?

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color: #006699;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #2089CC;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Sadly the source is:** http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

If you don't know why the 'sadly', please visit http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever in doubt go to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes). And here's an excerpt from the specs.

> Note that the A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited
>   rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color'
>   property of the A:hover rule

What you have is correct

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
   color: #006699;
   text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
   color: #2089CC;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

That's why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/7Wbsx/1/) works.

This below would be incorrect.

```
a:hover {
   color: #2089CC;
   text-decoration: underline;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active {
   color: #006699;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

That's why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/7Wbsx/) doesn't work.

Comment: just a small question, is a {...}; a:hover {...};, the same thing as a:link, a:visited, a:active{...}; a:hover {...};?

Comment: Isn't it superfluous to write `a:link, a:visited, a:active`? Wouldn't `a:link, a:visited` suffice?

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed way of including a style for each pseudoclass does not allow each pseudoclass to override the last. When you combine the styles like that, then they are simply applied together as a group.

For example, the `:active` pseudoclass comes last, so that it overrides `:focus`, or `:hover` pseudoclasses before it. This makes sense if you think of a link becoming active when clicked and you want a new style to be applied while the user is still hovering over the link with their cursor.

The true order is as follows:

```
a:link {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:visited {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:focus {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:hover {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:active {
  ⋮ declarations
}
```

Here is a [little reassurance](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclasses) for you.

Comment: hello, If all links share the same color/text-deco (except hover), how can I blend them into only 1 line without having trouble overriding something?

Comment: a lot of people use http://www.dotlesscss.org/ for working with css like a more robust programming language. It might help you out here if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CSS 2.1 specification on dynamic pseudo selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes):

> Note that the A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color' property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both activates and hovers over the A element.

Interestingly, the [current CSS3 draft specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#dynamic-pseudos) does not seem to mention this (or at least not as clearly).